# Alert script for /var/log/message

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, alert

Consider:

```
#!/bin/bash

msg=$(find /home/testaccount/test.log -mmin -30 -exec grep test.service {} \; | tail -1)
test -n "$msg" &&
    echo "$msg" |
    mail -r 'database@alert.etc' -s 'Database Aler' test@gmail.com
```

I have a script above. When there is a log with file *test.service*, it will email me. I have put it in cron and it will run every 30 minutes, but my problem now is it always emails the same log every 30 minutes.

Is there a way to email me once and then it will stop emailing me if it reads the same logs again?

I need to stop it from sending the same logs every 30 minutes and it will just email me if there is a new alert with *test.service* on it.

Comment: Is test.log a single file or a directory? `find` is for finding files, not lines in a file. But it looks like XY-problem. If the service is running by systemd, maybe it is better to use journalctl?

Comment: You need to check the timestamps on the log entries of interest, not on the whole log, and you need to select only the new-enough entries.  And then to send an e-mail only if any entries were in fact selected.

Comment: Or you could rename the file anytime you email a message. This does create new problems, (too many log files OR where to store them, and possibly a missed message once in a blue moon). Good luck.

Comment: Why do you use find, if you already know the full path to the logfile?

Comment: @user1934428 The use of find is questionable but not useless. It will find the file only if it was modified in the last 30 minutes, therefore it will grep the log only if it was modified since the last execution (assuming the script is called in a 30 minute interval).

Comment: @PaulPazderski : Good point! Certainly one way to do it....

Comment: How about using `grep -n` and saving the last grepped line somewhere in a file? If a new log entry arrived, the newly found line will have a higher line number, and you know that it is a new event, which needs to be mailed.

Comment: Another idea: Instead of checking every at certain intervalls, write a script which (similar to `tail -f`) is constantly reading from the logfile, and once it encounters the pattern, sends an email immediately. With this it is trivial to implement a certain "pause" time to avoid too many mails in succession,.

Answer (score 1):

You need some way to remember what you already saw. The most simple you could try is to store your *msg* in a file somewhere and the next time you get a message you `diff` it against your "state" file and only send a mail if there is something new.

As a more advanced approach you could build your script around [logtail](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/logcheck/-/blob/master/src/logtail2). It can give you only the new lines of a log file since the last invocation. (on Debian it is its own package `logtail`)

Or instead of scripting your own log watcher you can use an existing project like, for example [logcheck](https://logcheck.org/).